# laravel 5.1 only routing to home page, all other routes are coming 404 not found error, after hosting the local working site to the server

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I have pushed my laravel 5.1 application to server. In localhost, it works properly. but in server , only the home page is coming, no other routes working. I get 404 not found not found error. `jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4 POST http://mydomainurl/login/validate_login 404`  . I feel, it should traverse to `http://mydomainurl/applicationName/login/validate_login`. I dont know whats happening and where i have to update. 
I have enabled mode rewrite in apache and my .htaccess of application's public/ directory is as below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]   RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI} !^  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]  </IfModule>
```

I dont know much about .htaccess, but i copied from someone's answer. Please help

Comment: Make sure the Apache on your server has mod rewrite enabled and your `.htaccess` is correct.

Comment: please show your route entry on routes file for `login/validate_login`.

Comment: I got the solution finally, answering below

Answer (score 0):

After doing all the above modifications,And surfing around net, it didnt work.  Finally i understood that it may be because of url problem and just changed the url in ajax, like `url: "<?php echo url();?>/login/validate_login",`  It started working amazingly. Only in local host simply, `url: "login/validate_login",` works. 
Over all, things to be done are:
1: move public folder contents to your server's root folder(name it anything, eg: var/www/html/my_public). Update the .htaccess and index.php of it as explained in other answers. modify server.php, bootstrap/app.php if still didnt work. use url() with the calls. I achieved with this much :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably caused by your virtualhost config file. It should have "AllowOverride All" directive^

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin youremail@yahoo.com
    ServerName yoursite.com
    ServerAlias www.yoursite.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/yoursite.com/public"
    <Directory /var/www/yoursite.com/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```